# Как обновляют статусы заказов приложение такси?

Tags: android

Как обновляют статусы заказов приложение такси? Не таймер же они крутять с запросом,  у кого есть ответ или идеи

Comment: Могут и таймер, чому б нет :)

Comment: Раз речь об Android, то вероятней всего [Push Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: в комменте выше, дан ответ - это firebase. но можно конечно и свои велосипеды поделать. удобнее всего, мне кажется, будет long pool через retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мир протоколов очень обширен и вариантов очень много. Как пример - `WebSocket`, реализующий обратную связь между клиентом и сервером без необходимости обращаться к серверу для проверки состояния.

Answer (score 0):

Кручение таймера, пусть и не очень эффективное средство, но в современном мире дешевых гигагерцев и гигабайтов, вполне приемлемое решение.

А как именно они это сделали, помогут узнать программы apktool, dex2jar, fernflower